# Setting targeted version of plugin to avoid NoSuchMethodException

Tags: eclipse, api, eclipse-plugin, version, eclipse-pde

Im building a plugin in Eclipse 3.6, but I want it to be compatible with Eclipse 3.2.

I just got NoSuchMethodException, because I used some new API. is there any way to force eclipse to check if im not using too new methods?

When I created plugin i chose eclipse 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can make a new target platform for eclipse 3.2, and use that for development. Under **Preferences/Plug-in Development/Target Platform**, add a new platform using an older installation of eclipse, and select that as the platform for your workspace.